# css opacity affecting sibling image opacity

Tags: css

I have a simple `div` with two children, a `div` with an image and yet another `div` as below:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
    <div class="settingicon righty">
        <img src="/images/icons/setting.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="schedulepicker quat todaytoday">MONDAY</div>
</div>
```

I wanted so that when the second `div` is hovered, it reduces its opacity to `0.9`, so in my CSS my `.schedulpicker` has this rule:

```css
.schedulepicker:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

The problem is when it is hovered, the sibling image changes in opacity as well. Why is this so?

EDIT

Here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/VUzg9/4/

i am starting to wonder could it actually be the file itself.

EDIT 2

tested with jpg and gif, probably not the image issue.

Comment: what about giving your fiddle?

Comment: Works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VUzg9/1/. I used opacity: 0.5 to make the effect more obvious.

Comment: Does it occur in every browser, if not, what browser are you using?

Comment: Do you have more CSS rules that might be causing this? Or JavaScript?

Comment: schedulepicker don't have any sibling......make your problem clear

Comment: Is that exactly your code? Maybe the html is wrong ... something like this ... http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/VUzg9/2/

Comment: updated the jsfiddle, please have a look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the `position` (default is `static`) and a `z-index` for your image.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUzg9/6/)

```
.righty {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

The opacity you're setting on `#schedulepicker` is creating a new stacking context, and stacking contexts affect z-indexes. Since you didn't specify z-indexes manually, they're being auto assigned, and `#schedulepicker` has a higher value than `#settingicon` because it comes later in the markup.

**EDIT**

The [W3C color module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency) says the following:

> If an element with opacity less than 1 is not positioned,
>   implementations must paint the layer it creates, within its parent
>   stacking context, at the same stacking order that would be used if it
>   were a positioned element with ‘z-index: 0’ and ‘opacity: 1’.

Comment: thank you it works fine now, but i was just wondering why is z-index needed since its already above the div that was changing opacity (technically)

Comment: Technically it is not above or below - it is a sibling whose stacking order has not been defined. It appears to be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Great question - it looks like a bug.

You need to put a position and a z-index on it in order to get it to work.

```
.righty {
    float: right;
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VUzg9/9/

**EDIT**
I want to add to this answer because it's a very intriguing problem.

If we look at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers) it tells us that:

> ```
> In future levels of CSS, other properties may introduce stacking contexts, 
> for example 'opacity' [CSS3COLOR].
> ```

As @enfredH04 pointed out in his answer, as soon as the element changes opacity, it appears to then gain a stacking context (maybe Blink implemented a part of the spec [quoted above] that has not actually been written, or at least published, yet?) It's sibling does not have it's own stacking context and, thus, appears behind the element that changes opacity.

You can see this if you give the element a starting opacity of 0.9 - http://jsfiddle.net/VUzg9/11/ - at this point it must gain a stacking context. (Interestingly a starting opacity of 1 does not give it a stacking context).

Answer (score 1):

It's not changing the opacity of the "sibling", it's actually covering it up on-hover.

See two contrasting examples: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUzg9/4/)

Setting `position: relative` and a `z-index` seem to solve the issue