# css opacity affecting sibling opacity

Tags: html, css

[**EDIT:** Due to a mistake when creating this question from it's javascript based original, **this question is obsolete.**  ]

I have a HTML page which shows a matrix of the latest build states of our various products and multiple versions.

In this matrix, older builds are faded out by setting an `opacity: .5` through assigning an additional style class `"stale"`.
This matrix also shows results of tests performed. The test result element is a sibling to the build element and partially overlays it.

However, my problem now is, that if the 'build' element is faded out, the 'test' element is faded out too. First of all I'd like to understand why and secondly I don't want the 'test' result to be transparent.

```css
table { border: 1px solid darkgrey; }
td { border: 1px solid darkgrey; overflow: hidden; }
div { text-align: center; }
.build { 
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 10em;
    margin: 0.2em;
    padding: 0.2em;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}
.test {
    float: right;
    border: solid lightgrey 1px;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -0.8em;
    margin-right: -0.4em;
    // opacity: .99;      // workaround
}
.fail { background-color: rgb(255, 150, 150); }
.ok { background-color: rgb(170, 255, 170); }
.red { background-color: rgb(255, 150, 150); }
.green { background-color: rgb(150, 255, 150); }
.stale { opacity: .5; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Version</th>
    <th>Product A</th>
    <th>Product B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>
      <div class="build ok">success</div>
      <div class="test green">100%</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="build ok">success</div>
      <div class="test red">98%</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.0</td>
    <td>
      <div class="build ok stale">success</div>
      <div class="test red">99%</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="build fail stale">failure</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(tested with Firefox 52.1 ESR, Chrome 58)

I did some research and came across the SO question [css opacity affecting sibling image opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638151/css-opacity-affecting-sibling-image-opacity) but adding `position` and `z-index` (on either or both of the style classes `build` and `test`) did not solve my problem.

The only way I found so far to work around this behaviour is to add `opacity: .99;` to my `.test` style definition, but don't consider this a clean solution, and would like to better understand the reason of this behaviour.

Comment: _Validate_ your code before asking ... https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Damn. You're right. This mistake happend when reproducing my problem from the JavaScript based problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close your `<div>` tags properly.

The issue you are experiencing is a result of your browser's attempt to 'fix' your markup at run-time, the `<div>` elements are incorrectly placed within one another, so they are no longer siblings.

Fixing your markup solves your problem.

```css
table { border: 1px solid darkgrey; }
td { border: 1px solid darkgrey; overflow: hidden; }
div { text-align: center; }
.build { 
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 10em;
    margin: 0.2em;
    padding: 0.2em;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}
.test {
    float: right;
    border: solid lightgrey 1px;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -0.8em;
    margin-right: -0.4em;
    // opacity: .99;      // workaround
}
.fail { background-color: rgb(255, 150, 150); }
.ok { background-color: rgb(170, 255, 170); }
.red { background-color: rgb(255, 150, 150); }
.green { background-color: rgb(150, 255, 150); }
.stale { opacity: .5; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Version</th>
    <th>Product A</th>
    <th>Product B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>
      <div class="build ok">success</div>
      <div class="test green">100%</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="build ok">success</div>
      <div class="test red">98%</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.0</td>
    <td>
      <div class="build ok stale">success</div>
      <div class="test red">99%</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="build fail stale">failure</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is correct. Plus, he needs to add `.test { position: relative; }` in order for the `.test` not to be hidden by the `.build`.

Comment: Thanks, @DimitrisDamilos. That's what I've already learned from the other SO question, I referenced in my question.