# How do stop opacity breaking the href?

Tags: html, css, opacity

So I wanted background image to cut off at a certain point on the site. However now when I change the opacity the down arrow button won't work anymore. The other button on the site which doesn't have the background behind it does work.  I've listed the code below. I hope one of you can help me figure it out. :)

Does anyone know how this happened?

```css
 
html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#down{
 padding-top: 130px;
 opacity: 1.0;
}


 .bi-arrow-down-circle{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  
 }

.bg-image{
 
 height: 1350px;
 width: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
 background-position: center;
 margin-bottom: -100px;

}




body{

 margin: 0 auto;
 
}



 .navbar{
  margin-top: -150px
  margin-bottom: 45px;
 }

 #logo{
  margin-top: -1050px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 55%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1.0;
 }
 .carousel-inner img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
 }
 

 .row_1{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .column{
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 0 4px;
 }

 #grid{
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
 }

 .column #grid{
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  object-fit: contain;
  text-align: center;
 
  
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
/*#verpakking{
 height: 650px;
 width: 550px;
}

#verpakking_bs{
 height: 850px;
 width: 850px;
}*/

ul {
 padding: 10px;
}



#stoel{
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
}

.lijst_1{

}

.carousel_1{
 display: block;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.stoel{
 max-height: 50%;
}

#vrouwenkind{
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
}

.lijst_1{
 padding: 20px;
}

.footer{ 
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
 margin-top: 20px;

 padding: 15px;
}

.img1{
 background-image: url('../SC/sky.jpg');
 
}
```

```html
 

  

     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <title>SC</title>
         <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <script src="mail.js"></script>
         <script src="spinner.js"></script>
        
        </head>
        
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        <style>
        
        
         #contactbtn{
         display: block;
         margin: 27px auto;
         }
        
        
        </style>    
        <body>
                 <div class="bg-image img1" style="opacity: 0.25;"></div>
                 <div class="container">
                 <div class=row>
                   <div><img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" id="logo" src="./Seet Cuvers Logo.jpg" alt="SC logo"></div>
                 </div>
                
                </div>
                <a href="#down"><svg class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 7.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                </svg></a>
                
                
                
                
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light sticky-top">
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"/>
                </nav>
    <div class="container" id="down">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><blockquote>
      <dl class="lijst_1">
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
       
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
      
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
      
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
      </dl>
      </blockquote>
      </div>
        
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <img id="stoel" src="./SC.png">
  </div>
 </div>

  </p>
 </div>
</div>


 
  <button id="contactbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactModal">Contact ons</button>
 

 <div class="modal fade" id="contactModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title">Contact formulier</h4>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
     <form method="post" action="mailhandler.php" id="contactform">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email"> Email address</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" id="email" required>
       <span class="error">*<?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Voor- en achternaam</label>
       <input type="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Voor- en achternaam" id="name" required>
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="bericht">Bericht</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="bericht"></textarea>
      </div>
      
     </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-succes">Verzend</button>
     
    </div>
    <div class="succes_msg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;"><h3>Succes! We nemen zo spoedig mogelijk contact met u op</h3></div>
    <div class="error_msg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;"><h3>Er ging iets mis, probeer het later opnieuw.</h3></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
          </body>
```

Comment: Please give us a working example maybe in a jsfiddle, so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Welcome to SO! We cant help you until you provide us a complete or a part of working code, Code you mention above is incomplete ,

Comment: Your code seems to have a couple of issues! First, you forgot the quotation marks around the class name "row". Second, you don't provide a background image url for the class "bg-image". Third, your image class is not properly closed. Make sure to close it with " />" instead of just ">". Lastly, your "a href" directs to the id "#down" but there is no element in your code with the id of "down".  Just some helpful tips!

Comment: I'll edit it right now!

Comment: @Xenvi I forgot to paste the whole code, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: `opacity` can change stacking contexts. Your `<div class="bg-image img1">` element becomes placed _above_ your button on the z axis, when you add opacity. Adding `pointer-events: none` to the div would be an easy fix here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your "bg-image" div is covering the button due to its large height. I made the background of that div red so you can see that it is over the button. What is the purpose of this div? Is it meant to be behind the items?

NOTE: I replaced the images with some stock photos from unsplash so you can see how it looks in the demo, you can replace it back with your file locations.

```css
 
html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#down{
 padding-top: 130px;
 opacity: 1.0;
}

.container {
position: relative;
}

 .bi-arrow-down-circle{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  
 }

.bg-image{
 
 height: 1350px;
 width: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
 background-position: center;
 margin-bottom: -100px;

}




body{

 margin: 0 auto;
 
}



 .navbar{
  margin-top: -150px
  margin-bottom: 45px;
 }

 #logo{
  margin-top: -1050px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 55%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1.0;
 }
 .carousel-inner img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
 }
 

 .row_1{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .column{
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 0 4px;
 }

 #grid{
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
 }

 .column #grid{
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  object-fit: contain;
  text-align: center;
 
  
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
/*#verpakking{
 height: 650px;
 width: 550px;
}

#verpakking_bs{
 height: 850px;
 width: 850px;
}*/

ul {
 padding: 10px;
}



#stoel{
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
}

.lijst_1{

}

.carousel_1{
 display: block;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.stoel{
 max-height: 50%;
}

#vrouwenkind{
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
}

.lijst_1{
 padding: 20px;
}

.footer{ 
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
 margin-top: 20px;

 padding: 15px;
}

.img1{
 background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530281700549-e82e7bf110d6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1868&q=80');
}

#contactbtn{
         display: block;
         margin: 27px auto;
         }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <title>SC</title>
         <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <script src="mail.js"></script>
         <script src="spinner.js"></script>
        
        </head>
        
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <body>
                 <div class="bg-image img1" style="opacity: 0.25;"></div>
                 <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                   <div><img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" id="logo" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505628346881-b72b27e84530?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1868&q=80" alt="SeetCuvers logo" /></div>
                 </div>
                
                
                <a href="#down"><svg class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 7.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                </svg></a></div>
                
                
                
                
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light sticky-top">
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"/>
                </nav>
    <div class="container" id="down">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><blockquote>
      <dl class="lijst_1">
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
       
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
      
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
      
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
      </dl>
      </blockquote>
      </div>
        
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <img id="stoel" src="./Seet Cuvers.png">
  </div>
 </div>

  </p>
 </div>
</div>


 
  <button id="contactbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactModal">Contact ons</button>
 

 <div class="modal fade" id="contactModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title">Contact formulier</h4>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
     <form method="post" action="mailhandler.php" id="contactform">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email"> Email address</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" id="email" required>
       <span class="error">*<?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Voor- en achternaam</label>
       <input type="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Voor- en achternaam" id="name" required>
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="bericht">Bericht</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="bericht"></textarea>
      </div>
      
     </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-succes">Verzend</button>
     
    </div>
    <div class="succes_msg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;"><h3>Succes! We nemen zo spoedig mogelijk contact met u op</h3></div>
    <div class="error_msg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;"><h3>Er ging iets mis, probeer het later opnieuw.</h3></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
          </body>
```

Comment: I want the background to be cut off at the navbar, that's why I put it in a div. Forgive me, i'm new to this :)

Comment: However when opacity of the bg-image is 100% the button does work, isn't that strange?

Comment: Oh I see! And yes, I just spent a little time searching around and it appears it's because changing the opacity creates a new stacking context, which affects the z-indexes (the overlay and underlay positioning of elements in relation to other elements). You can read more on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638151/css-opacity-affecting-sibling-image-opacity

Comment: @Boudewijn I have updated the  code snippet so now it is working. What I did was wrap everything that is over the background image that was being covered (the div with class "row" and the down arrow href) into the .container element. Then, I added position: relative; to the .container element which brought the elements back in front of the background.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `margin-bottom:-100px;` placed in the `.bg-image` class. What this does is that it pulls in the elements below `bg-image` into its own region. So everything below `bg-image` upto 100px will be under `bg-image`, making them not clickable. Remove it to bring them out.

Edit (after you updated the question):
Your placement stratagies are not so good. You should consider nesting elements in one region in a single block. This will make your html structurally and semantically right.

```
.bi-arrow-down-circle {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -150px;  //remove this. This is not within the region of its parent space.
    opacity: 1.0;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this doesn;t work. The arrow still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't see your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are wanting something like this , opacity is given to different div i gave it to svg image

```css
 html{
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    #down{
     padding-top: 130px;
     opacity: 1.0;
    }


     .bi-arrow-down-circle{
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin-top: -150px;
      opacity: 1.0;
      margin-bottom: 100px;
      
     }

    .bg-image{
     
     height: 1350px;
     width: 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     /*overflow: hidden;*/
     background-position: center;
     margin-bottom: -100px;

    }




    body{

     margin: 0 auto;
     
    }



     .navbar{
      margin-top: -150px;
      margin-bottom: 45px;
     }

     #logo{
      margin-top: -1050px;
      margin-bottom: 200px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      max-width: 55%;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      opacity: 1.0;
     }
     .carousel-inner img{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%
     }
     

     .row_1{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      padding: 0 4px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      text-align: center;
     }

     .column{
      flex: 50%;
      padding: 0 4px;
     }

     #grid{
      width: 450px;
      height: 450px;
     }

     .column #grid{
      margin-top: 8px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      object-fit: contain;
      text-align: center;
     
      
     }
     @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .column {
        flex: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
      }
    }


    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .column {
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    }
    /*#verpakking{
     height: 650px;
     width: 550px;
    }

    #verpakking_bs{
     height: 850px;
     width: 850px;
    }*/

    ul {
     padding: 10px;
    }



    #stoel{
     height: 500px;
     width: 500px;
    }

    .lijst_1{

    }

    .carousel_1{
     display: block;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     height: auto;
     max-width: 100%;
    }

    .stoel{
     max-height: 50%;
    }

    #vrouwenkind{
     height: 500px;
     width: 500px;
    }

    .lijst_1{
     padding: 20px;
    }

    .footer{ 
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     color: #000000;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
     margin-top: 20px;

     padding: 15px;
    }

    .img1{
     background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg');
     
    }
```

```html
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <title>SC</title>
         <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <script src="mail.js"></script>
         <script src="spinner.js"></script>
        
        </head>
        
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        <style>
        
        
         #contactbtn{
         display: block;
         margin: 27px auto;
         }
        
        
        </style>    
        <body>
                 <div class="bg-image img1"></div>
                 <div class="container">
                 <div class=row>
                   <div><img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" id="logo" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg" alt="SC logo"></div>
                 </div>
                
                </div>
                <a href="#down">
                  <svg class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="opacity:0.25;">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 7.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                </svg></a>
                
                
                
                
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light sticky-top">
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"/>
                </nav>
    <div class="container" id="down">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><blockquote>
      <dl class="lijst_1">
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
       
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
      
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
      
       <dd>Sample text</dd>
      </dl>
      </blockquote>
      </div>
        
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <img id="stoel" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
 </div>

  </p>
 </div>
</div>


 
  <button id="contactbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactModal">Contact ons</button>
 

 <div class="modal fade" id="contactModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title">Contact formulier</h4>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
     <form method="post" action="mailhandler.php" id="contactform">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email"> Email address</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" id="email" required>
       <span class="error">*<?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Voor- en achternaam</label>
       <input type="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Voor- en achternaam" id="name" required>
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="bericht">Bericht</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="bericht"></textarea>
      </div>
      
     </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-succes">Verzend</button>
     
    </div>
    <div class="succes_msg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;"><h3>Succes! We nemen zo spoedig mogelijk contact met u op</h3></div>
    <div class="error_msg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;"><h3>Er ging iets mis, probeer het later opnieuw.</h3></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
          </body>
```